# Combine array with the same keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me to convert this array?

This is the initial state:

```js
var arrOne = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    phone: '111',
    pass: '123'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mike',
    phone: '222',
    pass: '456'
  },
    {
    name: 'Steve',
    phone: '333',
    pass: '789'
  },
];
```

I need to convert it to:

```js
var result = {
  name: ['John', 'Mike', 'Steve'],
  phone: ['111', '222', '333'],
  pass: ['123', '456', '789']
}
```

Comment: Please provide code you have tried and what didn't work about it. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service but a platform for helping with concrete problems where you are stuck with your own approach. So always provide this data in your question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each member of the array resulting in a single output value.

You can use `reduce()` in the following way:

```js
var arrOne = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    phone: '111',
    pass: '123'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mike',
    phone: '222',
    pass: '456'
  },
    {
    name: 'Steve',
    phone: '333',
    pass: '789'
  },
];

var result = arrOne.reduce((a,c) => {
  for (var k in c) {
    a[k] = a[k] || [];
    a[k].push(c[k]);
  } 
  return a;;
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

`reduce` makes this transformation straightforward; build an object of arrays and push corresponding keys onto it:

```js
var arrOne = [{name:'John',phone:'111',pass:'123'},{name:'Mike',phone:'222',pass:'456'},{name:'Steve',phone:'333',pass:'789'},];

const result = arrOne.reduce((a, e) => {
  for (const k in e) {
    if (!(k in a)) {
      a[k] = [];
    }
    
    a[k].push(e[k]);
  }
  
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below solution takes the keys of first object in array, and collects those keys in final object. So if you add more keys to your object, you wont have to change anything.

```js
var arrOne = [{name:'John',phone:'111',pass:'123'},{name:'Mike',phone:'222',pass:'456'},{name:'Steve',phone:'333',pass:'789'},];

console.log(
  Object.keys(arrOne[0]).reduce(
      (acc, key)=>({...acc, [key]: arrOne.reduce((acc,item)=>acc.concat(item[key]),[])})
  , {})
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you create the object that will hold the results, then you iterate over your array to bind your results

```
var result = {
    name: [],
    phone: [],
    pass: []
}

arrOne.map(u => { 
    result.name.push(u.name);
    result.phone.push(u.phone);
    result.pass.push(u.pass);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dynamic approach by mapping all keys to new objects and join these objects to a single one.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'John', phone: '111', pass: '123' }, { name: 'Mike', phone: '222', pass: '456' }, { name: 'Steve', phone: '333', pass: '789' }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => 
        Object.assign(
            ...Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: [...(r[k] || []), v] }))
        ), {});
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as this:

```js
var arrOne = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    phone: '111',
    pass: '123'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mike',
    phone: '222',
    pass: '456'
  },
    {
    name: 'Steve',
    phone: '333',
    pass: '789'
  },
];
/*
var result = {
  name: ['John', 'Mike', 'Steve'],
  phone: ['111', '222', '333'],
  pass: ['123', '456', '789']
}
*/
var result = {};
var keys = Object.keys(arrOne[1]); //console.log(keys);
//init empty array for result
keys.forEach(current=>{
  result[current] = [];
});
//add value to result
arrOne.forEach(current=>{
  for (let i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
    result[keys[i]].push(current[keys[i]]);
});
console.log(result);
```